# if array in list of arrays returns Value Error

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy.arrays and I'm trying to add a check if the array already exists in the list.

for example

```
list = []
list.append( np.array( 1, 2, 3) )
list.append( np.array( 3, 2, 1) )

if not np.array( 2, 3, 1) in list:
    list.append( np.array( 2, 3, 1) )
```

I'm getting an error

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

How can check for this?

Comment: Don't use builtin keyword `list` as variable name unless you are actively looking at creating bugs...

Comment: `np.array( 1, 2, 3)` will give you another ValueError, use `np.array( [1, 2, 3])` instead.

Comment: The problem arises because `np.array([1,2,3])==np.array([x,y,z])` returns a boolean array of the same size - it does element-wise comparisons.  This contrasts with a list comparison which produces a scalar true/false.  So `if` and `in` tests don't work well with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
lst = []
lst.append(np.array(1, 2, 3))
lst.append(np.array(3, 2, 1))

# pretty ugly solution, admittedly
if not any(np.logical_not(np.any(
    np.array(lst) != np.array(2, 3, 1), axis=0))):
    lst.append(np.array(2, 3, 1))
```

If the size/types of the arrays inside `lst` vary, this might work better:

```
if not any(not np.any(x != np.array(2, 3, 1)) for x in lst):
    lst.append(np.array(2, 3, 1))
```

That said, this is a very strange thing to do in the first place.

Comment: Oddly the array [2, 3, 1] is added any number of times to lst if in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

With lists:

```
In [240]: alist = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]
In [241]: [2,3,1] in alist
Out[241]: False
In [242]: [3,2,1] in alist
Out[242]: True
In [243]: [x == [3,2,1] for x in alist]
Out[243]: [False, True]
```

With arrays, `==` is element-wise  (with broadcasting):

```
In [244]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
In [245]: np.array([3,2,1])==arr
Out[245]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

We can use `all` (or `any`) to reduce one or other axis:

```
In [246]: np.all(np.array([3,2,1])==arr,axis=1)
Out[246]: array([False,  True])
```

and a `any` to complete the `in`:

```
In [252]: np.any(Out[246])
Out[252]: True
```

That ambiguity error is raised by `numpy` when a multivalued boolean array is used in a Python context that requires a scalar True/False.  That includes `if`, and `and/or`, as well as the `in` test.

Another way to picture that row wise comparison:

```
In [247]: [np.array([3,2,1])==x for x in arr]
Out[247]: [array([False,  True, False]), array([ True,  True,  True])]
In [248]: [np.all(np.array([3,2,1])==x) for x in arr]
Out[248]: [False, True]
```